# Python mail puts unaccounted space in Outlook Subject line

Tags: python

I've written a simple Python script which used MIMEMultipart and SMTPLib to send a mail to an array of recipients.
The code looks something like this:

```
import smtplib
import sys

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

sender='foo@bar.com'
recipients='someguy@bar.com'
subject='A pretty long subject line which looks like this'
mail_server='microsfot_exchange_server_ip'
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
body='Body of the Email'
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['from'] = sender
msg['to'] = ", ".join(recipients)
s = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

This sends a mail successfully, but the Subject like in Outlook Mail client looks something like this:

```
 A pretty long subject line which looks       like this
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the relevant headers of the message created by Python (output of `msg.as_string()`) and of the e-mail received by the client (Outlook).

Comment: Also: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Here’s what it looks like in the headers:
`Subject: A pretty long subject line which looks
 like this`
I’m using Python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you've hit [Issue #1974](http://bugs.python.org/issue1974):

Long e-mail headers should be wrapped. This process is called "header folding" and is described in [`RFC822`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.html). However, RFC822 seems to be a bit ambigous about how exactly header folding should take place.

Python in versions earlier than `2.7` / `3.1` happened to do it in a way that caused the issued you described with certain mail clients (using tab `\t` as the continuation character).

In the bug report there has been a [workaround](http://bugs.python.org/issue1974#msg84755) suggested: Make your subject line a header object like this:

```
from email.header import Header

# ...

msg['Subject'] = Header(subject)
```

I just verified this, and it does indeed use spaces instead of tabs as continuation characters, which should solve your problem.

Comment: +1. Aside: RFC2822 (which supersedes RFC822) describes header folding and unfolding unambiguously.

Comment: Another possible workaround would be RFC2047-encoding the header.

Comment: FWIW the current RFC is 5322.

Answer (score 2):

Your subject line is longer than 78 chars, and is being broken up by `.as_string()`. The first few chars are on the subject line, and the remaining chars are on one or several continuation lines.

When Outlook reconstructs the original subject line, it does so incorrectly.

You can try to avoid this by avoiding continuation lines, like so:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from email.generator import Generator
def my_as_string(msg):
  fp = StringIO()
  g = Generator(fp, mangle_from_=False, maxheaderlen=0)
  g.flatten(msg)
  return fp.getvalue()

...

s.sendmail(sender, recipients, my_as_string(msg))
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.generator.html#email.generator.Generator
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.as_string
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html

Comment: screwgoth: I'll leave my answer up in case it has value to posterity. But, you should prefer Lukas' answer.

Comment: Yeah. Your solution would probably work as well.But I think it's slightly a round-about way. I do appreciate introducing me to the 'Generator' class though.